# Media library Images

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I am using visual studio for windows phone.
Can we see the Image stored in media library in windows phone 7 emulator ?
Is there any specific file location of such files?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to get images with [`MediaLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary_members.aspx) class? Or you want to access images outside of your application, i.e. manage images with file manager?

```
MediaLibrary m = new MediaLibrary();
foreach (var p in m.Pictures)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(p.Name);
    Stream s = p.GetImage();
}
```

Comment: My application takes a screenshot and store it in media library....I want to see this image so that i can know what changes should I make....

Comment: Set unique names to your screenshots, so you always can find them later. `m.Pictures.Select(i => i.Name.StartsWith("my_app"));`

Answer (score 1):

[How to: Use the Photo Chooser Task for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394019%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

```
try
{
    photoChooserTask.Show();
}
catch (System.InvalidOperationException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("An error occurred.");
}

void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ChosenPhoto.Length.ToString());

        //Code to display the photo on the page in an image control named myImage.
        //System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
        //bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        //myImage.Source = bmp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the images from image library there is a [photo chooser task class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.photochoosertask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

```
   private void loadPhoto_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        photoChooserTask.Show(); 
    }
```

This now opens up a gallery of photos to choose from.